# Program runs in Visual Studio debugger. Executable doesn't function properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, crash, exe

Firstly, this is my first ever question on here (I am used to reddit), so please be kind. Secondly, I have been recently hired to a company and was handed this task (one of my firsts) by my project manager. Thirdly, this solution/program was developed entirely by a different person who no longer is with the company, and I cannot contact.

A part of our larger product and base implementation has been running into issues. This GUI based application was originally built in Windows 7 under an older SDK (around win7 time) and has been developed using Visual C++. The most recent, stable release was said to have built properly using Windows 10 SDK, and was built for x86 processors. It produced a working executable file for our customers to use. When I was handed this task, I was told that the development environment (Visual Studio) on other team members' machines was causing an issue where the solution would not build. They had tried using different windows SDKs, running in debug, running in release, using breakpoints. All of those solutions seemed to cause different and confusing errors.

I can usually figure out most issues if they are code related; however I am just not sure if the code is the issue here. When I brought down the solution from our repository and built it (release mode, x86), it built perfectly fine. It has built fine since. It builds properly in debug mode and the program will run properly in the debugger for both the debug and release modes. It doesn't build for x64, but I was told it wasn't supposed to. Basically, I can run the program in Visual Studio and it works flawlessly. When I try to launch the executable it seems to abort right away, or stops with only briefly running (I never see a window).

I first tried building it with multiple different SDKs and none of them resulted in a functioning executable. I then checked to make sure that the antivirus was not blocking the executable (I checked in the .exe's properties). Everything checked out OK. Both the machine and network are monitored by the company, but again I have been told that this shouldn't be stopping the .exe from running. It then seemed to be very possible that the .exe was having issues with dlls. I would like to say that I tried to do research on dlls but it was confusing and I am still not comfortable at all with the topic. That being said, I used a dependency program to figure out which dlls the program was needing/using. A few showed up as missing/failing: "api-ms-win-core-wow65-l1-1-0.dll", "ext-ms-win-core-winrt-remote-l1-1-1.dll", "ext-ms-win-com-suspendresiliency-l1-1-0.dll". I have NO clue whether or not this is actually true and/or is causing an issue with my program, nor would I know how to fix it. The best news here is that there is no logging being done. I cannot actually debug since it opens and shuts down right away after a proper build. I tried running in cmd.exe, but it failed identical to running in directory.

I am running Windows 10. Using VS 2017. I will be bald by the end of the week. If you have questions on specifying certain things, please let me know. I am humble enough to admit when I have no idea about certain things so feel free.

Comment: Have you tried running your program from `cmd.exe` to see what output it produces? If it actually crashes, [force enable crashdumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) for your executable to see if that produces more information. You can also use something like Procmon to inspect any system calls that your process makes. Also keep in mind that running from visual studio  sets a *different working directory* than clicking the exe.

Comment: A first guess would be different environment settings/command line arguments between VS debugging and running the program manually. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if you needed to pass some flags to it (which are set in the project options in VS but not present when running the executable by hand). Start it within `cmd.exe` as suggested above and see what happens.

Comment: "_Firstly, this is my first ever question on here (I am used to reddit), so please be kind._" Did you try taking the [tour], and reading through [ask], and [help]? For instance, we don't require TLDRs here, as this is not a forum. If you don't read the question: you can't answer it.

Comment: Your issue is a common side-effect of uninitialized variables.  Debuggers often initialize all the variables before starting.  There are no guarantees when running with the executable.

Comment: @Botje I did run it in cmd.exe sorry for not clarifying. It has the same issues as if running the .exe from the directory. I also made sure that the depended upon files were in the proper directory. Also, I did take the tour, but yah...

Comment: *"I cannot actually debug since..."* - If it successfully runs from the VSIDE debugger, then you already *are* debugging it. Just running the program via F10  (step-over)  should take you to your first line in `main` or `WinMain`. (I'm curious whether a *release* build (not a debug build) also runs successfully from the VS IDE. Finally, note that running from the IDE normally defaults to using the *project* folder as the working directory, whereas running via cmd uses whatever folder your shell is in at the time, or via explorer which uses whatever folder the exe lives in . That's important.

Comment: Just as a side-note, the windows dependency walker (depends.exe) is incredibly broken (in Windows 10) and will return many false positives, so don't rely on it if that's what you were using.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was actually referring to when i run the executable. I am using dependency by lucas.